# Parse JSON of two dimensional array in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, json

Problem is, my JSON string looks like this:

```
jsonString =  [["1","100"],["2","200"],["3","300"]]
```

I need to make a two dimensional array out of it in Java.
If I write

```
JSONObject jObs = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

I get the following error:

```
A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of [["1 ...
```

How can I parse a two dimensional array out of this string? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JSON you've got is for an array, not an object. You probably want

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
```

Full sample code:

```
import org.json.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "[[\"1\",\"100\"],[\"2\",\"200\"],[\"3\",\"300\"]]";
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
        JSONArray first = array.getJSONArray(0);
        System.out.println(first.getString(1)); // Prints 100
    }
}
```

Comment: +vote After nearly one hour surfing on the net i find what i need